# Emit Smoke From Hair

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation, hair

Does anyone know of a way to set a smoke/fire's emitter be hair strands. The end goal of this is to have a horse's mane and tail to be on fire.

[image]

Comment: As far as I know you can't emit particle systems from othe particle systems. Make a dummy mesh roughly the shape of the mane, and emit from there.